# Unable to delete cache object in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

I am implementing CakePHP caching to store query result in cache. for that I have done following configurations in bootstrap.php file:

```
Cache::config('routing', array(
'engine' => 'File',
'duration' => '+1 week',
'probability' => 100,
'path' => CACHE . 'Route' . DS,
```

));

now I am writing data in to cache using:

```
        Cache::write('route_data',$url,'routing');
```

its writing cache object in to my tmp/cache/Route directory and I am able to  read this  cache object successfully. I have to delete this object in one scenario so I am deleting it using:

```
 Cache::delete('route_data','routing');
```

but cache object is not deleting. is there any configurations or parameters I am missing ?

Comment: Can you try with using just `Cache::delete('route_data');` ?

Comment: @Rikesh: tried but not working . I seen in cache directory cache object is written in file named 'cake_route_data'

Comment: That is unusual try read **path** from `Cache::settings('routing')` in your project

Comment: @walkingRed : fetched path from Cache::settings('routing') and then tried to delete key by passing full path then also it's not deleting

Comment: @GaneshPatil check permission on tmp catalog - and try with 777

Comment: @walkingRed: recursive 777 permissions are there from all directories  inside tmp directory

Comment: @GaneshPatil that is weird problem :D Try debug method Cache::delete step by step.